# Ifort compiler doesn't recognize interface in Fortran

Tags: interface, fortran, intel-fortran

When I try to compile code under the statement with ifort it returns error as:

```
    error #8169: The specified interface is not declare
```

But it works perfectly on gfortran, for some reason I have to use intel compiler to compile this work. The language I am using is Fortran. The reason for this is that the 'ifort' compiler does not see the variables in Interface. So I develop a module called Var to do fix that. And Use it in every blocks. But it returns error:

```
This USE statement is not positioned correctly within the scoping unit.
```

The var module is like following:

```
MODULE VAR
      CHARACTER(50) :: callbackID
END MODULE
```

how can I fix the problem thanks alot! My compiler version is ifort 12.1.0

```
      MODULE DEMO
      USE VAR
      INTERFACE
        SUBROUTINE callback_prototype(callbackID)
            USE VAR
            CHARACTER(*) :: callbackID
        END SUBROUTINE callback_prototype
      END INTERFACE

      PROCEDURE( callback_prototype ), POINTER :: f_ptr => NULL()

      CONTAINS
      SUBROUTINE set_callback(func)
         IMPLICIT NONE
         EXTERNAL :: func

          f_ptr => func
          call HELLO
      END SUBROUTINE

      SUBROUTINE invoke_callback(callbackID)
          CHARACTER(*) :: callbackID
          if (associated(f_ptr)) call f_ptr(callbackID)
      END SUBROUTINE

      SUBROUTINE HELLO

      IMPLICIT NONE

      !dosomthing


      END SUBROUTINE
      END MODULE
```

Comment: Sorry I updated it now

Comment: You are not using Fortran 90, but at least Fortran 2003, because of procedure pointers.

Comment: And your code compiles OK with ifort 14.0.

Comment: So I need to update my ifort...

Comment: Did you really compile exactly the code you posted?

Comment: @VladimirF So you think for ifort 14.0 it is working for the interface and the style that I wrote for using the USE statement?

Comment: Well, there are some problems with your code, try to fix them first. Gfortran finds them and marks the program as incorrect. What is the sense of the module VAR at all and why the dummy argument has the same name as the module variable?

Comment: @VladimirF I followed this site http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2006/10/05/domestic-or-imported I know it's weird but It is doing something like that and my compiler didn't regnized it

Comment: @VladimirF It is really weird that I wrote a dummy code of the same interface, it works with my ifort compiler...I need to figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code as presented is not legal fortran.  The use statement inside the interface body makes accessible a name that is the same as a dummy argument.  This violates the scoping rules of the language.

The use statement inside the interface body would appear to be superfluous.

Comment: Yes, that's what I have tried to address in the later comments.

Comment: The problem is indentation error in my code, if I move all those use statement, I can compile with no indentation in the first line. But when I do indentation in the firstline(for some reason I have to). I don't know how to fix it. Can you help me? @VladimirF@lanH

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the reason why you want the use statement in the interface in the first place. Even the interface can be skipped, because you have the right procedure accessible:

```
PROCEDURE( invoke_callback ), POINTER :: f_ptr => NULL()
```

Comment: but the Module have to do indentation operation first because there is #ifdef _SLAVE in front. but when I put all the stuff inside module as an indentation. It doesn't work also...